# why is my data a tuple and how can I change this so I can sort the data

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I am using rpy2 to do some statistical analyses in R via python. After importing a data file I want to sort the data and do a couple other things with it in R. Once I import the data and try to sort the data I get this error message:

```
TypeError: 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an index
```

The last 2 lines of my code are where I am trying to sort my data, and the few lines before that are where I import the data.

```
root = os.getcwd()
dirs = [os.path.abspath(name) for name in os.listdir(".") if os.path.isdir(name)]
for d in dirs:
    os.chdir(d)
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    files_to_analyze = (glob.glob("*.afa"))
    for f in files_to_analyze:
        afa_file = os.path.join(cwd + '/' + f)
        readfasta = robjects.r['read.fasta']
        mydatafasta = readfasta(afa_file)
        names = robjects.r['names']
        IDnames = names(mydatafasta)            
        substr = robjects.r['substr']
        ID = substr(IDnames, 1,8)
        #print ID
        readtable = robjects.r['read.table']
        gps_file = os.path.join(root + '/' + "GPS.txt")
        xy = readtable(gps_file, sep="\t")
        #print xy
        order = robjects.r['order']
        gps = xy[order(xy[:,2]),]
```

I don't understand why my data is a tuple and not a dataframe that I can manipulate further using R. Is there a way to transform this into a workable dataframe that can be used by R?

My xy data look like:

```
Species AB425882    35.62   -83.4
Species AB425905    35.66   -83.33
Species KC413768    37.35   127.03
Species AB425841    35.33   -82.82
Species JX402724    29.38   -82.2
```

I want to sort the data alphanumerically by the second column using the `order` function in R.

Comment: this creates a tuple: `order(xy[:,2]), `  The comma at the end.  What does order look like, and xy?  Can you print out their type and give us an example of what they contain

Answer (score 0):

There is a quite a bit of guesswork since the example is not sufficient to reproduce what you have.

In the following, if `xy` is an R data frame, you will want to use the method dedicated to R-style subsetting to perform R-style subsetting ([see the doc](http://rpy2.readthedocs.org/en/version_2.7.x/vector.html#extracting-r-style)):

```
# Note R indices are 1-based while Python indices are 0-based.
# When using R-style subsetting the indices are 1-based.
gps = xy.rx(order(xy.rx(True, 2)),
            True)
```